# Regex to find Integers in particular string lines

Tags: java, regex, string

I have this regex to find integers in a string (newlines). However, I want to filtrate this. I want the regex to find the number in certain lines, and not others.

String:

```
 String test= "ytrt.ytrwyt.ytreytre.test1,0,2,0"
+"sfgtr.ytyer.qdfre.uyeyrt.test2,0,8,0"
+"sfgtr.ytyer.qdfre.uyeyrt.test3,0,3,0";



pattern = "(?<=,)\\d+";

    pr = Pattern.compile(pattern);

    match = pr.matcher(test);
    System.out.println();
    if (match.find()) {


        System.out.println("Found: " + match.group());

    }
```

This regex find the integers after the comma, for all the lines. If I want a particular regex to find the integers in the line containing "test1", "test2", and "test3". How should I do this? I want to create three different regex, but my regex skills are weak.

First regex should print out 2. The second 8 and the third 3.

Answer (score 1):

You can expand your pattern to include `test[123]` in the lookbehind, which would match `test1`, `test2`, or `test3`:

```
String pattern = "(?<=test[123][^,]{0,100},[^,]{1,100},)\\d+";
Pattern pr = Pattern.compile(pattern);
Matcher match = pr.matcher(test);
System.out.println();
while (match.find()) {
    System.out.println("Found: " + match.group());
}
```

The `,[^,]` portion skis everything between two commas that follow `testN`.

I use `{0,100}` in place of `*` and `{1,100}` in place of `+` inside lookbehind expressions, because Java regex engine requires that lookbehinds had a pre-defined limit on their length. If you need to allow skipping more than 100 characters, adjust the maximum length accordingly.

[Demo.](http://ideone.com/3AceM1)

Comment: Thank you, but I wanted a separate regex for each string to match. I tried modifying your code like this, but no success. Thank you again.
pattern = "(?<=test1,[^,],)\\d+";

What I want the pattern to do is to take the integers only from the line containing "test1" which is 2.

Comment: @SandeepSingh Your modification should work perfectly fine ([demo](http://ideone.com/7ZX60p)).

Comment: Yes it did, but I forgot to change it. I had the string as: "ytrt.ytrwyt.test1.ytrwyt,0,2,0";
Will it still match?

Comment: I want the regex to be like: "contains test1". Wherever the test1 is, i want it to match.

Comment: @SandeepSingh Please see the edit. Here is an [updated demo](http://ideone.com/7ZX60p).

Comment: Thank you very much. Can this be more dynamic? What if the line changes and becomes much longer and I still want to match test1 + the integers?

Comment: @SandeepSingh You can put 1000 or 10000 in place of 100 right away, it does not matter. Unfortunately, Java has this requirement on lookbehinds that they must be limited to some max length, which can be determined at the time the pattern is compiled.

Comment: I see, but that's enough for me. I tried your code and the matcher only matches the first integer after the comma and not the rest. Isn't the "d+" the right command? Thank you.

Comment: @SandeepSingh `d+` matches a single integer that may be composed of multiple digits. `+` would stop as soon as it finds any other character, e.g. a comma `,`.

Comment: Can I somehow fix this? So it matches the three first integers, or the two first integers, before it stops?

Comment: @SandeepSingh Yes, you can, as long as you don't mind getting all integers in a single string with commas ([demo](http://ideone.com/fIBQpi)).

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following `Pattern` and loop for this:

```
String test= "ytrt.ytrwyt.ytreytre.test1,0,2,0"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        +"sfgtr.ytyer.qdfre.uyeyrt.test2,0,8,0"
        + System.getProperty("line.separator")
        +"sfgtr.ytyer.qdfre.uyeyrt.test3,0,3,0";
//                          | "test" literal
//                          |    | any number of digits
//                          |    |  | comma
//                          |    |  | any number of digits
//                          |    |  |    | comma
//                          |    |  |    | | group1, your digits
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("test\\d+,\\d+,(\\d+)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);
while (m.find()) {
    // prints back-reference to group 1
    System.out.printf("Found: %s%n", m.group(1));
}
```

**Output**

```
Found: 2
Found: 8
Found: 3
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also use capturing groups to extract the test number and the other number from the string:

```
String pattern = "test([123]),\\d+,(\\d+),";

...

while (match.find()) {
    // get and parse the number after "test" (first capturing group)
    int testNo = Integer.parseInt(match.group(1));
    // get and parse the number you wanted to extract (second capturing group)
    int num = Integer.parseInt(match.group(2));
    System.out.println("test"+testNo+": " + num);
}
```

Which prints

```
test1: 2
test2: 8
test3: 3
```

**Note:** In this example parsing the strings is only done for demonstration purposes, but it could be useful, if you want to do something with the numbers, like storing them in a array.

**Update:** If you also want to match strings like `"ytrt.ytrwyt.test1.ytrwyt,0,2,0"` you could change `pattern` to `"test([123])\\D*,\\d+,(\\d+),"` to allow any number of non-digits to follow `test1`, `test2` or `test3` (preceding the comma seperated ints).

Comment: I don't want it as dynamic as [123]. I want a separate regex just for test1. Is ""test1\\D*,\\d+,(\\d+),"" correct?

Comment: @SandeepSingh: The only thing you need to do then, is replacing the `([123])` part with the test number (`1`, `2` or `3`) and then you need to replace `match.group(2)` with match `match.group(1)` since you removed the first capturing group. It's not that difficult.